# In Rust, how can I create a function which will accept a "Marker Component" as a type parameter?

Tags: generics, rust, functional-programming, traits, dry

I'm currently looking at the [Rust Sokoban](https://sokoban.iolivia.me/) tutorial, playing with the code as I type it in, to see how I can "improve" it without breaking it.  In the chapter on [Pushing boxes](https://sokoban.iolivia.me/c02-03-push-box.html) they introduce two "marker components" to "tell us which entities are movable and which aren't":

```
#[derive(Component, Default)]
#[storage(NullStorage)]
pub struct Movable;

#[derive(Component, Default)]
#[storage(NullStorage)]
pub struct Immovable;
```

Later, we have the following code:

```
                let mut mov: HashMap<(u8, u8), Index> = (&entities, &movables, &positions)
                    .join()
                    .map(|t| ((t.2.x, t.2.y), t.0.id()))
                    .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>();
                let mut immov: HashMap<(u8, u8), Index> = (&entities, &immovables, &positions)
                    .join()
                    .map(|t| ((t.2.x, t.2.y), t.0.id()))
                    .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>();
```

where `&entities` is an instance of `Entities`, `&positions` is an instance of `WriteStorage<Position>`, and `&movables` and `&immovables` are respectively instances of `ReadStorage<'a, Movable>`, and `ReadStorage<'a, Immovable>`.

As someone neurotic about DRY code, the above two functions really gets my hackles up, and I feel the desire to refactor that away, but I haven't been able to figure out how to compose a function which can handle the different types for `&movables` and `&immovables`.

For example, if I try this function:

```
fn collect<T>(entities: &Entities, storable: &ReadStorage<T>, positions: &WriteStorage<Position>)
    -> HashMap<(u8, u8), Index> {
    (&entities, &storable, &positions)
            .join()
            .map(|t| ((t.2.x, t.2.y), t.0.id()))
            .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>()
}
```

and invoke it like:

`let mov: HashMap<(u8, u8), Index> = collect(&entities, &movables, &positions);`

or like:

`let mov: HashMap<(u8, u8), Index> = collect::<Movable>(&entities, &movables, &positions);`

... compiling fails with:

> error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: specs::Component` is not satisfied
> --> src\resources\input_system.rs:95:46
> | 95  | fn collect(entities: &Entities, storable: &ReadStorage, positions: &WriteStorage)
> |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `specs::Component` is not implemented for `T`
> |     ::: C:\Users\BrianKessler.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\specs-0.17.0\src\storage\mod.rs:143:29
> | 143 | pub struct MaskedStorage<T: Component> {
> |                             --------- required by this bound in `MaskedStorage`
> | help: consider restricting type parameter `T`
> | 95  | fn collect<T: specs::Component>(entities: &Entities, storable: &ReadStorage, positions: &WriteStorage)
> |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> error: aborting due to previous error
>
> For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
> error: could not compile `rust-sokoban`
>
> To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.

For example, if I try this function (as per @AlexeyLarionov's suggestion):

```
fn collect<T: specs::Component>(entities: &Entities, storable: &ReadStorage<T>, positions: &WriteStorage<Position>)
    -> HashMap<(u8, u8), Index> {
    (&entities, &storable, &positions)
            .join()
            .map(|t| ((t.2.x, t.2.y), t.0.id()))
            .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>()
}
```

compiling fails with:

> error[E0599]: the method `join` exists for tuple `(&&specs::Read<'_, EntitiesRes>, &&specs::Storage<'_, T, Fetch<'_, MaskedStorage<T>>>, && specs::Storage<'_, Position, FetchMut<'_, MaskedStorage<Position>>>)`,
> but its trait bounds were not satisfied   -->
> src\resources\input_system.rs:94:14    | 94 |             .join()    |
> ^^^^ method cannot be called on `(&&specs::Read<'_, EntitiesRes>, &&specs::Storage<'_, T, Fetch<'_, MaskedStorage<T>>>, & &specs::Storage<'_, Position, FetchMut<'_, MaskedStorage<Position>>>)`
> due to unsatisfied trait bounds    |    = note: the following trait
> bounds were not satisfied:
> `&&specs::Read<'_, EntitiesRes>: specs::Join`
> which is required by `(&&specs::Read<'_, EntitiesRes>, &&specs::Storage<'_, T, Fetch<'_, MaskedStorage<T>>>, &&specs::Storage<'_ , Position, FetchMut<'_, MaskedStorage<Position>>>): specs::Join`
> `&&specs::Storage<'_, T, Fetch<'_, MaskedStorage<T>>>: specs::Join`
> which is required by `(&&specs::Read<'_, EntitiesRes>, &&specs::Storage<'_, T, Fetch<'_, MaskedStorage<T>>>, &&specs::Storage<'_ , Position, FetchMut<'_, MaskedStorage<Position>>>): specs::Join`
> `&&specs::Storage<'_, Position, FetchMut<'_, MaskedStorage<Position>>>: specs::Join`
> which is required by `(&&specs::Read<'_, EntitiesRes>, &&specs::Storage<'_, T, Fetch<'_, MaskedStorage<T>>>, &&specs::Storage<'_ , Position, FetchMut<'_, MaskedStorage<Position>>>): specs::Join`
>
> error: aborting due to previous error
>
> For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
> error: could not compile `rust-sokoban`
>
> To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.

Do I really need to introduce a trait to make this work?
If so, what should that trait look like?
And what other changes would I need to make?
Will I need to add so much complexity that the cure becomes worse than the disease?

Comment: Silly question, but did you try declaring your function with `fn collect<T: specs::Component>`, as compiler gracefully suggested?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov, not such a silly question.  I'm new enough at Rust not to have interpretted the compiler's feedback as a suggestion that I should do this.  I will try it.  Thanks.  :-)

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov, I tried but it lead to another error (see above).

Comment: You seem to take all three objects by double references, why so? I'm not familiar with `specs::Join` trait, but from [docs](https://docs.rs/specs/0.15.1/specs/join/trait.Join.html) it seems it's implemented for objects and for single references. Try passing objects like so `(entities, storable, positions).join()...blahblah`, eliminating double references

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov, I'm taking them as I found them, but I will try it, thanks.  :-)

Comment: Well in your original code you take by them as single references,

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov, this works. :-)  Now that I look for it, I think I understand what you mean regarding the "double reference"... Working with references will take a bit of getting used to.  :-)

Comment: It's typically not a problem though, because even if you have a single object with many levels of references like `&&&&&&&Vec<_>`, you'll still be able to call methods of it just fine, similarly `&(A, B)` can be easily casted to `(A, B)`, while `(A, &B)` cannot be casted to `(A, B)`, unless you define some cast explicitly

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov, Cheers for the help and encouragement!  Feel free to add your answer if you'd like me to accept it.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, there are two sources of errors:

1. Methods operating on `ReadStorage<T>` or `WriteStorage<T>` require `T` to be a `Component`, luckily both `Movable` and `Immovable` already were, so to fix it we can simply constraint the `T` on this trait. Declaration of the function would look like so `fn collect<T: specs::Component> (...)`
2. Because of copy-pasting, the `.join()` method was called on object `(&entities, &storable, &positions)`, where `entities`, `storable`, `positions` are references already as specified in the function declaration, thus `.join()` was called (simply speaking) on type `(&&A, &&B, &&C)`, while it's defined for `(&A, &B, &C)`. To fix it
   we need to call `(entities, storable, positions).join()` inside the `collect` function

The final version of the code would look like this:

```
fn collect<T: specs::Component>(entities: &Entities, storable: &ReadStorage<T>, positions: &WriteStorage<Position>)
    -> HashMap<(u8, u8), Index> {
    (entities, storable, positions)
            .join()
            .map(|t| ((t.2.x, t.2.y), t.0.id()))
            .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>()
}
```

Comment: A bit of a tangent, but is it frequently (or ever) useful to have multilevel references, or is this something which would usually be a code smell to watch out for?

Comment: Hardly ever. Sometimes multi-level mutable references are useful. And the iterator chain functions sometimes produces multi-level references as a side effect.